# How to add conditions in Unity unit test hooks for test case

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, nunit

Similarly to how SpecFlow has tag features where one can add a @mytag to a scenario and in hooks, say for example in the before scenario, I can do a check if @mytag, do some code.

Is there a way to have my hooks in unity to conditionally do something before the scene starts?

```
[UnitySetUp]
public IEnumerator UnitySetUp()
{
    //if scenario contains this tag, do this code
    if(mytag)
    {
      do some code
    }
    yield return null;
}
```

Comment: Could you extend your example a bit? I don't really understand what exactly `mytag` would be ...

Comment: In this example, the customconfig tag gets checked in hooks before scenario where I can say ok, this test cases needs a custom config, copy some file into my directory before the scenario starts. This works in web just fine, but how do I do this in Unity `@customconfig
Scenario: I can format a button
 Given This is set
 When this is clicked
 Then that is formatted`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It's using TestContext.

```
[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    if ((string)TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties.Get("tag") == "mytag")
        //do some code
}

[Test]
[NUnit.Framework.Property("tag", "mytag")]
public void TestWithTag()
{
   
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).